# Spelunky HTML5 Saving

Tags: version-differences, spelunky-hd, spelunky-html5

Loving the free version of Spelunky from the Chrome store (even moreso that its an actual application and not a link to somebody's website).

Is there some functionality missing from this game though?  From what I understand you can save your progress and best games and whatnot in the paid version of Spelunky HD, but in the app I have it never remembers how far I got or how well I did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Spelunky and Spelunky HD?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142865/what-is-the-difference-between-spelunky-and-spelunky-hd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save your progress in individual runs in SpelunkyHD (or the executable version of the original Spelunky), but it does keep track of your statistics (deaths, high scores, enemies/places/items discovered) and contains unlock able characters not available in the free version of Spelunky.

This question will outline the differences between HD and the original (the HTML5 version is a clone of the original version) further:

[What is the difference between Spelunky and Spelunky HD?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142865/what-is-the-difference-between-spelunky-and-spelunky-hd)

Comment: Definitely noticing that high scores are not tracked in the HTML5 version.

Comment: @espais try using default browser settings.